# Can you use Group By to group people into age groups

Tags: sql, group-by, range

I want to use `group by` to group the list of these people by age group.
For example :

> - 20s - 7
> - 30s - 4
> - etc

Will the query look like this at all?

```
With age as (
case 
when age < 13 then 'Under 13'
when age between 13 and 19 then 'Teens'
when age between 20 and 29 then '20s'
when age between 30 and 39 then '30s'
when age between 40 and 49 then '40s'
when age between 50 and 59 then '50s'
when age between 60 and 69 then '60s'
when age between 70 and 79 then '70s'
when age > 80 then 'Over 80'
end as AgeGroup from NameList
```

[image]

Comment: What results do you want?  What database are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `select` in a CTE.  I think you want:

```
With age as (
      select nl.*,
             (case when age < 13 then 'Under 13'
                   when age between 13 and 19 then 'Teens'
                   when age between 20 and 29 then '20s'
                   when age between 30 and 39 then '30s'
                   when age between 40 and 49 then '40s'
                   when age between 50 and 59 then '50s'
                   when age between 60 and 69 then '60s'
                   when age between 70 and 79 then '70s'
                   when age > 80 then 'Over 80'
              end) as AgeGroup
      from NameList
     )
select age.agegroup, count(*)
from age
group by age.agegroup
order by min(age.age);
```

Comment: Very nice this can we use `count(1)` instead of `count(*)` for better performances.

Comment: @jishansiddique . . . The only database that I know of where that makes a difference is Postgres and in Postgres, `count(1)` is SLOWER:  https://www.citusdata.com/blog/2016/10/12/count-performance/.

Comment: Thank you for proper guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Try Below Query

```
With age,AgeGroup as (
select age,case 
when age < 13 then 'Under 13'
when age between 13 and 19 then 'Teens'
when age between 20 and 29 then '20s'
when age between 30 and 39 then '30s'
when age between 40 and 49 then '40s'
when age between 50 and 59 then '50s'
when age between 60 and 69 then '60s'
when age between 70 and 79 then '70s'
when age > 80 then 'Over 80'
end as AgeGroup from NameList)select * from age group by age,AgeGroup
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternate way to get the counts without using CTE:

```
    SELECT CASE WHEN age < 13               THEN 'Under 13'
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 13 AND 19 THEN 'Teens'
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20s'
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30s'
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40s'
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50s'
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN '60s'
                 WHEN age BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN '70s'
                 WHEN age > 80 THEN 'Over 80' 
                 END AS AgeGroup , COUNT(1) AS Counts
    FROM NameList
    GROUP BY CASE WHEN age < 13               THEN 'Under 13'
                   WHEN age BETWEEN 13 AND 19 THEN 'Teens'
                   WHEN age BETWEEN 20 AND 29 THEN '20s'
                   WHEN age BETWEEN 30 AND 39 THEN '30s'
                   WHEN age BETWEEN 40 AND 49 THEN '40s'
                   WHEN age BETWEEN 50 AND 59 THEN '50s'
                   WHEN age BETWEEN 60 AND 69 THEN '60s'
                   WHEN age BETWEEN 70 AND 79 THEN '70s'
                   WHEN age > 80 THEN 'Over 80' 
                   END
```